# Blazor event only works correctly while debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a component that tracks the number of words typed into a text area. The issue is that the word updates after writing the first word then stops. To make it fire off the event again I have to click out of the text area and click back in, then type again. The strange part about this is that when I am debugging and stepping through the word count updates without any issues.

I just need it to update as I am typing like when I am debugging.

My Blazor component:

```
<div class="row">
    <textarea id="test" class="form-control" @bind="text" @onkeypress="WordsLeft"></textarea>
    <p>Words left: @(MaxCount - CurrentWordCount)</p>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int MaxCount { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string text { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public int CurrentWordCount;

    public void WordsLeft()
    {
        CurrentWordCount = text.Split(' ').Length;
    }
}
```

Order of how it behaves:
Open page (words left: 500) -> type a word (words left: 499) -> Type another 2 words (words left 499) -> click out of text area -> click back in to text area -> type another word (words left: 496)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working version of your code:

```
@page "/Test1"
<div class="row">
    <textarea id="test" class="form-control" @bind="text" @oninput="WordsLeft"></textarea>
    <p>Words left: @(MaxCount - CurrentWordCount)</p>
</div>

@code {
    public int MaxCount { get; set; } = 500;

    public string Text { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public int CurrentWordCount;

    public void WordsLeft(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentWordCount = e.Value.ToString().Length;
    }
}
```

`text` only gets updated when you exit the control. The easiest way to get the actual entered value on each keystroke is through the `ChangeEventArgs`.   Also it's generally better to use the `oninput` event.